# Simple vs. Composite Hypothesis Question

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, logistic, mathematical-statistics

I am looking at one of the questions in the qualifying exam, where a multiple logistic regression model is being fitted, where the response is about dying.

The question says that there are multiple potential risk factors such as age, gender, smoking, etc., and they have to be controlled for simultaneously.

One of the questions asked to assess the statistical significance of smoking. Specifically, we have to show the null hypothesis and tell if this is a simple hypothesis.

So, I know that for the null hypothesis, the coefficient estimate for smoking is equal to 0 (smoking is not statistically significant). But my answer key says that it is a composite hypothesis.

I am confused. I thought this was a simple hypothesis, as it testing if it is equal to zero. Is this because multiple predictors have to be controlled simultaneously?

What will make it a simple hypothesis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Novices often misunderstand the distinction between simple and composite, so let me illustrate them with a simple example.

(a) Consider a simple random sample $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ with $X_i\sim N(\mu, 1)$ and suppose we wish to test

$$H_0:\mu=0\quad\text{against}\quad H_1:\mu=1.$$

Then, both $H_0$ and $H_1$ are simple hypotheses since, under either of them the model is fully known, e.g., there are no unknown parameters left.

(b) Let again the sample be $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ with $X_i\sim N(\mu, 1)$ but we wish to test
$$H_0:\mu=0\quad\text{against}\quad H_1:\mu\neq 1.$$
Here, $H_0$ is simple, whereas $H_1$ is a composite hypothesis. Indeed, under $H_1$, there are many possible choices for the unknown parameter $\mu$.

(c) The sample is $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ with $X_i\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and we wish to test
$$H_0:\mu=0\quad\text{against}\quad H_1:\mu=1.$$
In this case, both $H_0$ and $H_1$ are composite hypotheses, even though we have fixed $\mu$. Indeed, the unknown nuisance parameter $\sigma^2$ is still lurking in the model.

(d) The sample is $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ with $X_i\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and we wish to test
$$H_0:\mu=0\quad\text{against}\quad H_1:\mu\neq 0.$$
Again, both $H_0$ and $H_1$ are composite; $H_0$ it is due to the presence of $\sigma^2$ and for $H_1$ because of the unknowns $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Thanks, but why for my case that the coefficient estimate for smoking is 0 in the logistic regression model for null hypothesis is composite hypothesis? My question did not say anything about normality.

@utobi

Comment: @Texas2022, your case is essentially equivalent to the case (d) above. That is, even though under $H_0$, the coefficient for smoking is set to 0, you have other unknown regression coefficients to deal with, both under $H_0$ and under the alternative. Thus both $H_0$ and $H_1$, in the case of a multiple logistic regression, are composite.

Comment: That make sense. So if it was all of regression coefficient in the hypothesis, it would be simple? @utobi

Comment: Yep. If all betas are fixed, no unknowns are left, so the hypothesis is simple.